# ImageView in getChildView not anymore updating after calling OnChildClickListener

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, expandablelistview

Right now I am stuck with an issue about expandablelistview. The problem is that there seems to be a conflict between the onChildClickListener and the getChildView.

Briefly: When one clicks on a groupitem two submenuitems pops up. In these (2) submenuitems there is an imageview that loads an image. And if one of these items are clicked another imageview are generated - this time from the onChildClickListener method. So far so good. But - if one continues to expand another groupitem in the app - the imageview that was generated from the onChildClickListener-method is still there (not the imageview from the getChildView).

I found a similar question on stack that you can find here. But there the problem was between the listener and getGroupView.

[custom views not updating with OnGroupClickListener on ExpandableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372867/custom-views-not-updating-with-ongroupclicklistener-on-expandablelistview)

What is the reason for this? Has it anything to do with caching? Any suggestion how to solve all these? I have tried several methods ... invalidate(), invalidateviews(), setWillNotCacheDrawing(true), setItemsCanFocus(false) and so on.

So to summarize: when the onchildclicklistener is called - the image from the getchildview is not loaded anymore - only the image from the listener.

below the listener

```
expListW.get().setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        Object e = (Object)adapterW.get().getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        int nmbr_childs = adapter.getChildrenCount(groupPosition);
        final int group_position = groupPosition;

        switch (childPosition) {
        case 0:
            if (nmbr_childs > 1 ) {
                myVoice = soundPool.load(PhraseActivity.wr.get(), sound[group_position][0], 2);
                soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                          int status) {
                            soundPool.play(myVoice, 20, 20, 1, 0, 1f);
                      } 
                });
                speakerImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.single);
                speakerImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.smile);
            }
            else {
                myVoice = soundPool.load(PhraseActivity.this, sound[group_position][0], 2);
                soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                          int status) {
                            soundPool.play(myVoice, 20, 20, 1, 0, 1f);
                      } 
                });
                speakerImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.single);
                speakerImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.smile);
            }   
            break;
        case 1:
            myVoice = soundPool.load(PhraseActivity.this, sound[group_position][1], 2);
            soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                      int status) {
                        soundPool.play(myVoice, 20, 20, 1, 0, 1f);
                  } 
            });
            speakerImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.single);
            speakerImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.smile);
        break;              
        }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

and here is the getChildView-method ...

```
      public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      final ViewHolder holder;
      if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_subphrase, parent, false);
          holder = new ViewHolder();
          holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label_single);
          holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label_couple);
          holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
          holder.imageView2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.couple);
          convertView.setTag(holder);

      } else {  
          holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
      }
      final int nChildren = getChildrenCount(groupPosition);

      final View v = convertView;
      switch (nChildren) {
        case 1:
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(0);
            holder.imageView2.setBackgroundResource(0);
            holder.text.setText(null);
            holder.text2.setText(contents[groupPosition][childPosition]);
            holder.imageView2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.man_woman_3);
            extra(groupPosition, category, holder.text, convertView, parent); 


            ViewTreeObserver vto = convertView.getViewTreeObserver();
            vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);  //vet inte om denna metod är nödvändig
                holder.imageView2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation3);
                frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) holder.imageView2.getBackground();
                frameAnimation.start();   
            }});
            break;

        case 2:
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(0);
            holder.imageView2.setBackgroundResource(0);
            holder.text2.setText(null);
            holder.imageView.invalidate();
            holder.text.setText(contents[groupPosition][childPosition]);
            switch (childPosition) { // Switch-villkor för man eller kvinna. 
                case 0: // Man.
                    holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.man_33);
                    break;
                case 1: // Kvinna.
                    holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.woman_33);
                    break;
            }
            break;
      }
      notifyDataSetChanged();
      return convertView;
  }
```

Very greatful for help!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved my own question. Just call bringToFront() for the actual imageView. For example if an imageHolder is keeping the imageView:

holder.imageView.bringToFront().